# Pandas: Combine subsetting and filtering

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that I have the following data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':list('aaaabbbb'),
                   'hour':[1,3,3,2,5,6,6,2],
                   'id':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]})
df
```

What I'd like to do is find the most common (mode) unique hour per group.

The following gets me a count of hours per group.

```
df[['group','hour']].groupby(['group']).agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
```

Now let's say that I want to subset the hour. I can't seem to figure that out in one line.

```
df[['group','hour']] & df.hour==3].groupby(['group']).agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
```

That doesn't work. Any ideas on how to combine hour==3 and selecting columns together in one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc`:

```
df1 = (df.loc[df.hour==3, ['group','hour']]
         .groupby(['group'])
         .agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  group  hour
0     a     3
```

Comment: Provide an alternative :-)

Answer (score 2):

`value_count` is the way , but you can also try `mode`

```
df.loc[df.hour==3, ['group','hour']].groupby(['group']).hour.apply(lambda x : x.mode()).reset_index()
Out[519]: 
  group  level_1  hour
0     a        0     3
```